# How to interpret this formula?

Tags: calculus, statistics, discrete-mathematics

I understand bits and pieces of this formula, but have no idea how to interpret its full meaning/calculation - believe me I have tried. It seems the formula would always have Tn = 0.

$\displaystyle T_n=1.3800\frac{1}{h_j}\sum_{k=1}^{h_j}\{med_{j\ne i}|x_{(i)j}-x_{(i')j}|\}_{(k)}$

The original source is from Rousseeuw and Croux (6.5 extensions and outlook):

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221996720_Alternatives_to_Median_Absolute_Deviation

And here:

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1904/e9cfd50d31736a7a9fd41e71811c4dcec041.pdf

How would one calculate {1,1,-2,-1,2} using the above mentioned formula?

Comment: Incomprehensible. I don't know what $med$ means. I don't know what $x_{(i)j}$ refers to. I don't know what $\{\_\}_{(k)}$ means. I don't know what $\{\,1,1,-2,-1,2\,\}$ means.

Comment: med = median, {1,1,−2,−1,2} = data imputed into formula, x(i)j I am not sure, hence the reference to the sources and the asking of the question "how to interpret this formula".

Comment: How does "data imputed (input?) to formula" relate to any of the symbols in the formula? Is the data the values of the $h_j$? Does it have something to do with the $x_{(i)j}$? You'll make it easier for people to help you, if you include the information from the source, instead of asking them to go off and retrieve it themselves.

Comment: You're right. I should have done that and will edit the post in the morning. Although, part of the reason for posting links to the sources was because I really did not understand the formula itself, hence why I thought sources would be easier since I would not be able to explain it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably $|x_{(i)j}-x_{(i')j}|$ is an absolute value so always non-negative and usually positive, making $T_n$ usually positive

The $\displaystyle T_n=1.3800\frac{1}{h_j}\sum_{k=1}^{h_j}\{\text{med}_{j\ne i}|x_{(i)j}-x_{(i')j}|\}_{(k)}$ looks too complicated to understand (I suspect $j$ and $i^\prime$ have been confused), so instead let's try to decipher Rousseeuw and Croux (6.5) $$T_n=1.3800\frac{1}{h}\sum_{k=1}^{h}\{\text{med}_{j\ne i}|x_{(i)}-x_{(j)}|\}_{(k)}$$ where $h=[n/2]+1$.

So you suggested an input of $\{1,1,-2,-1,2\}$ which ordered is $(-2,-1,1,1,2)$, with $n=5$ and $h=3$

```
i  x_{(i)}  x_{(j)}    |x_{(i)}-x_{(j)}|    median
1    -2    -1, 1,1,2        1,3,3,4           3
2    -1    -2, 1,1,2        1,2,2,3           2 
3     1    -2,-1,1,2        3,2,0,1           1.5
4     1    -2,-1,1,2        3,2,0,1           1.5
5     2    -2,-1,1,1        4,3,1,1           2
```

so the ordered medians are $(1.5,1.5,2,2,3)$

making $T_n= 1.3800\times \frac{1}{3} (1.5+1.5+2) = 2.3$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Wouldn't h = 3.5 if n=5 then h = [5/2] + 1 = 3.5? Unless I am missing something

Comment: $h$ has to be an integer since you are summing over an index from $k=1$ to $k=h$.  I assumed that [$[x]$ was an *integer part* function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Notation)